VirtualBox　マウスで「続行」のボタンが押せません
ノートブックでWindows11です。
VirtualBoxは9.0
ディストリビューションは
AlmaLinux-9.3-x86_64-dvd
「インストール時の使用する言語を設定して下さい。」
の画面でマウスで「続行」のボタンが押せません。
原因と対処方法を教えて下さい。
ディスクトップでは上手くいったのですが、ノートPCでハマってしまっています。
ポインティングディバイスはPS/2にしています。
一旦削除してやり直しましたが、やはり同じ問題がおきます。
エンターキーを押しても続行できません。
他の言語をクリックすると反応します。
矢印キーで移動することもできるのですが、続行ボタンがクリックできません。
ディスクトップと同じVirtualBoxのバージョンで再インストール。
再度、起動しましたが変化はありませんでした。

VirtualBoxの2024年4月30日時点の最新版は7.0.16です。「9.0」となると未来のバージョンなのですが、何か間違っていませんか？

キーボードが使える状態なら、Alt キーと (インストーラの画面で) ボタンに割り振られているショートカットを使うことでも操作できるはずです。

解決しました。
VirtuBoxの設定で「PS/2マウス」から「USBタッチパッド」に変更して再起動したら動きました。ありがとうございました。

解決した場合にはコメント欄で終わらせず、個別の回答として投稿してください。
